# Bounds of integration for PDF

Tags: probability, integration, statistics

Given the PDF $\ f_{XY}(x,y)=8xy $

$\ 0<x<1 $

$\ 0<y<x $

Find $\ f_Z(z) $
Where
$\ Z=\frac{Y}{X}$

---

I want to calculate $\ F_Z(z) $ so that I can derive it and find $\ f_Z(z) $.

$F_{Z}(z)=  \iint_{\frac{Y}{X}<z} (8xy)dydx = P(Z<z) $

How do I find the bounds for the integration?

Comment: Draw the region described  by the two conditions on x and y, it helps you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, by definition, since $X\ge0$:
$$F_Z(z)=P(Z<z)=P(Y<zX)=\iint_{y<zx} 8xy\ dydx.$$

Look at the following figure now:

[image]

It is easy to see that 
$$\iint_{y<zx} 8xy\ dydx=
\begin{cases}
8\int_0^1x\int_0^{zx}y\ dy\ dx,& \text{ if } z<1\\
1,& \text{ if } z\ge1
\end{cases}=$$
$$=
\begin{cases}
4\int_0^1x[y^2]_0^{zx}\ dx,& \text{ if } z<1\\
1,& \text{ if } z\ge1
\end{cases}
=$$
$$=
\begin{cases}
4z^2\int_0^1x^3\ dx=z^2,& \text{ if } z<1\\
1,& \text{ if } z\ge1
\end{cases}
.$$

(And, of course, the result is $0$ if $z<0$.)